# It sound the narrator saying "icky shave" in this video

Tags: meaning-in-context

Watch exactly 45th second of the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hsY6DHvod0).

Does he saying ***icky shave*** in that point in this video[it sounds like *icky shave*], if it is so **what does it mean?** It sounds he is saying "it is the icky shave which delivered the fatal wound"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about transcription of audio, not about learning the English language.

Comment: The word is [ricochet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ricochet)

Comment: I'm not sure what re-opening this question would accomplish. There's not much else to say about it beyond what has already been said, and I don't see it as a question that folks might want to refer to in the future. If someone else has the same trouble understanding the same section of the video, it's very likely they wouldn't be able to find this question and answer and would have to ask a new question anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

It says:

> President Sadat is hit by thirty seven bullets, but it is a **ricochet** which delivers the fatal wound.

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but it made me giggle when I saw your answer, compared to the mis-hear. Made my day :)